# Context-free grammar for $a^ib^ic^id^{3i}$

Tags: context-free

I'm trying  to make a context-free grammar for $L=\{a^ib^ic^id^{3i}\mid i>0\}$.

I could make a grammar for $a^ib^jc^jd^{3i}$. But I can't make the grammar for the special case that $i=j$ as it is in $L$.

Comment: Your language is not context-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pumping lemma to show that this language is not context-free.

Suppose it is context-free and let $n$ be the constant of the pumping lemma. Consider the word $u = a^nb^nc^nd^{3n}$. $u$ can be written $u = vwxyz$ with:

- $|wxy| \leq n$
- $|wy| > 0$
- $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, vw^kxy^kz\in L$.

Now using the first condition, $wxy$ can be written with at most two letters from the initial four. You can take it from here to find a contradiction.